# git pull from one remote branch to another

Tags: git, visual-studio

In visual studio.com, in a repository i can do a pull request from one remote branch to another remote branch via web UI.

This is how its done on my current team, theres a master branch, devTest branch and a branch for each developer. Each dev pushes their changes to their own remote branch, and when the time comes for testing they push changes from their own remote branch to the shared devTest branch.

Although I can push from my the branch on my local machine to my remote branch, i cannot figure out how to then, via command line, push from my remote branch to the remote devTest branch.

Is this possible via the command line on my machine or only via the rcsi.com website?

Comment: Simple answer is NO. You can't create pull requests using `git`. If you want to create a pull request through terminal, [`github cli`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create) is what you have to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pull requests are not a part of the git protocol, but they are often implemented by services that host git repositories.

If you need the review feature often associated with the PRs in the hosting services, then you need to use their features (web UI or APIs). When using only the git protocol you would have to go directly to the merge (which is the final step of a PR after reviewing).

If that is acceptable for you to merge directly then you could do this from your cli:

```
git checkout devTest
git pull
git merge userDevBranch
git push
```